# How to cancel upgrade?

Tags: big-pharma

Sometime I accidentally click on an upgrade button in Big Pharma, upgrading the wrong ingredient or technology.

Is it possible to cancel these upgrade and get the points back so they can be spent elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having played the game through-out it's beta / early-access period and another 10 or so hours since release **I am not aware of any way to refund upgrades**.

Comment: I've been playing the game a lot now and haven't found it yet either. There does seem to be an option for mods, so it's probably possible there. But I've gotten used to it and don't really upgrade by accident anymore.